# The "chez moi" in the sentence "J'ai déjà ma dose chez moi."

Tags: sens

> Garde tes reproches ! J'ai déjà ma dose **chez moi**.

I’m not sure of the precise meaning of the "chez moi" here. Does it mean:

> Keep your criticisms for yourself! I have already enough of criticisms to deal with **on my side**, as is.

or:

> Keep your criticisms for yourself! I have already reached my limit **in/inside me** of taking criticisms.

How does this sentence compare with the version without "chez moi":

> Garde tes reproches ! J'ai déjà ma dose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chez moi](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/chez%20moi) n'a pas plusieurs sens, ça veut dire « à la maison », c'est l'endroit où on habite habituellement. La personne qui dit :

> Garde tes reproches ! J'ai déjà ma dose chez moi.

veut dire qu'elle reçoit déjà beaucoup de reproches chez elle de la part des personnes qui vivent avec elle.

En disant simplement :

> Garde tes reproches ! J'ai déjà ma dose.

on enlève la précision sur l'origine des reproches qui peuvent venir de l'entourage familial du locuteur mais aussi de ses collègues de travail, de ses amis...

Comment: To @Laure This conversation takes place in the speaker's workplace, so the "chez moi" may well refer to his workplace rather than his home? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA I doubt it, just can't see how it could mean the workplace. If the speaker meant their workplace the would say something like: *à mon travail* or *ici* or *de la part des autres*, but *chez moi*, (*chez toi*, *chez lui*, etc...) is the equivalent of the English "at home".